# Cannot run OpenJFX's non modular maven sample

Tags: java, maven, javafx, openjfx

Title is pretty self explanatory, I've downloaded the non-modular maven sample code for JavaFX from OpenJFX (from here) and I can't run it.

It compiles without any error but when I try to run it I get this error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.openjfx:hellofx >-------------------------
[INFO] Building hellofx 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ hellofx >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ hellofx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Toolchain in javafx-maven-plugin null

[ERROR] Command execution failed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.691 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-07T08:56:47+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/johan/Desktop/hellofx"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea is appreciated as I don't even understand the `Cannot run program Java` part.
I ran the javafx:compile then the javafx:run in Maven.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I cleaned both my Java and Intellij installation and got it to work. The `JAVA_HOME` variable was indeed not set and Intellij couldn't find the project because of the flatpack install used by the software manager (at least I think that's the problem since it couldn't find my JDK as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable is set correctly.  This will allow the `javafx-maven-plugin` to find the correct `java` command needed to run your application.

Follow this guide, choosing the relevant section for your OS:

- [Set JAVA_HOME on Windows 7, 8, 10, Mac OS X, Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux)

Also, use the current version of the maven JavaFX plugin, `0.0.8`, though that is not your core issue.